# update one table according to data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables, `table1` with cols `v1` and `v2`, `table2` with cols `v3` and `v4`.

I want to update `table2.v2` if `table1.v1` have a matching value in `table2.v3`.

I have the following code that seems to work

```
UPDATE table1
SET v2 = 99
WHERE exists(select v3 from table2
where table2.v3=table1.v1);
```

I also tried with an intersect version which failed (updates both rows of v2)

```
UPDATE table1
SET v2 = 99
WHERE exists(select v1 from table1
intersect select v3 from table2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use intersect in this query because you have not used any joining condition between the sub query and outside query. I do think Exists expects that kind of condition.

Try using this,

```
UPDATE table1
SET v2 = 99
WHERE v1 in (select v1 from table1
intersect select v3 from table2);
```

Answer (score 4):

For this we have two Answers

1)With Inner Join

```
UPDATE table1
SET v2 = 99
FROM table2 
     INNER JOIN table1
     ON table2.v3= table1.v1
```

2) With in clause

```
 UPDATE table1
 SET v2 = 99
 Where v1 in (Select v3 FROM table2)
```

Comment: shankar bhau , ata kar bindast pane matdan kara, +1 mazyakadun...jai maharashtra.

Comment: for some reason solution 1 did not work for me, maybe it's because I am using oracle?                                                 Error starting at line 31 in command:
UPDATE table1
SET v2 = 99
FROM table2 
     INNER JOIN table1
     ON table2.v3= table1.v1
Error at Command Line:33 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: yes In Oracle gives such type of error . In oracle you can use second option.For such type error please go through the URL:-http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm

Answer (score 2):

As per my point of view first check the value of table by 'If Exists' as below and than applied to update.

```
IF EXISTS
(
 select V1 from T2
 where v1 in (select v1 from t2)
)

BEGIN
UPDATE T1
SET v2 = 99
end
```

Cheers.....

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the following is your requirement:

```
UPDATE table1
SET v2 = 99
WHERE v1 IN (select v3 from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join to update table.

```
UPDATE table2
SET v2 = 99
From table2 Inner Join table1 on  table1.v1=table2.v3
```

Comment: for some reason this solution did not work for me, maybe it's because I am using oracle? Error starting at line 31 in command: UPDATE table1 SET v2 = 99 FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.v3= table1.v1 Error at Command Line:33 Column:1 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended" *Cause: *Action: